# Get object id doing query by userID and Date

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Im very new at iOS programming so i started to build apps using Parse. So i have class "Photo" and it stores all the photos of all users. So i need to build a query that returns latest posted image by the current user. So i did this.

```
-(PFQuery*)checkImage{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)

{

    if (!error) {

        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);

        NSLog(@"Objects: %@",objects);

       //next query here?


    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];

return query;

}
```

it returns all photos of current user which is fine but the next step is to check the latest posted image and return from the record objectID and i don't know where to put the next query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add constraint where you can control the createdAt field in parse. Or another suggestion, you can order the query based on createdAt and via setting limit, you can retrieve the latest result as query result is equal to limit value. Hope this helps.

Regards.